# Image Align Center - CHROME - FIREFOX - IE

Tags: html, css, browser

This is our website link

http://navttc.org/index.php/home

Here you can see our partners scrolling using marquee, i have set the images to align center and even try to do with css i.e `style="margin: auto;"` but still images are not align in Firefox and IE only center align in CHROME can you tell me what could be the reason behind this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this CSS code:

```
.bjmod-content
{width:128px; margin:auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try styling the image to `display: block` in order for it to work with auto margins.